# Raster Symbology Calculate Area Acres

Tags: raster, symbology, raster-calculator, area

Using ArcMap, I am trying to classify/consolidate the symbology of these agriculture classes into 3 categories: Hay, Pasture/Grass, and Cropland. I also need to find the sum of acres of each of these 3 categories after reclassifying them. The file is currently in a raster format.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate the question, this does not tell us what is required of the answer.

Comment: I need to consolidate all of the crop classes within the raster into one cropland class and one color of symbology. Then calculate the total sum of acreage that it covers within the entire raster polygon.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reclassify in to your consolidated classes (Reclassify tool). Ensure the resulting classes are integer values
2. In ArcMap’s table of contents, right-click and open the attribute table for the reclassified raster. The “count” field represents the number of cells in each raster class; multiply these by cell size^2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this approach:

1. Use the reclassify tool to Merge your different agriculture classes.
2. Use Raster to Vector to convert your Raster into a Polygon vector(Make sure to give proper projection to the file).
3. Go to the Attribute table of your newly created vector and create a new column named "Acreage"
4. Right Click on the column and click "Calculate Geometry"
5. Select Calculate Area and the unit for the Area Measurement.

Hope this does it.

References:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012554

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm